# How to call a php function clicking a checkbox without using AJAX or anything

Tags: php, html

a normal 'checkbox' input 'form' which i have in echo"" of PHP

```
<input type='checkBox' onclick='if(this.checked) {selectItem(".$row['serial_no'].",".$user_id.")}'>


function selectItem($serial_no,$user_id){echo $serial_no;}
```

both of them are in PHP file....why the function is not called when checkbox is clicked?

Comment: php is a server side language, why won't you use ajax 'or anything'?

Comment: why did you downvote the question? it's clear that he's a begginer, so  stop being surly. Just answer explaining that there's no way to escape from using ajax 'or anything' and try to tell him the way or suggest an interesting tutorial

Answer (score 1):

because PHP only runs when the page loads, not after. This is why you need to use Ajax to get values from PHP

Comment: cant i just click the checkbox and run a php function??